# HistogramList is much Slower in 10.2 vs 10.1

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics, version-10

While I was running a code I wrote using version **10.1**, I noticed that in version **10.2** the running time of the same code was more than twice as long. After some digging, I figured out the culprit is `HistogramList`. The following should reproduce the problem:

```
$Version
lis = Riffle[RandomReal[100, 10^6], -1];
First @ AbsoluteTiming @ HistogramList[lis, {0, 6, 0.02}]
```

> "10.1.0  for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)"
>
> 0.894027

```
$Version
lis = Riffle[RandomReal[100, 10^6], -1];
First @ AbsoluteTiming @ HistogramList[lis, {0, 6, 0.02}]
```

> "10.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)"
>
> 2.43526

Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm it on OS X.  I get about the same numbers.

Comment: [There do seem to be several changes in the underlying implementation.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hmrl72pi5a8yhdi/Screenshot%202015-07-24%2009.04.36.png?dl=0)

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for confirming. It was driving me crazy since there was no mention of any changes in the documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like this has not only been corrected in *Mathematica* **10.4**, but has been made about **7** times faster than **10.1**.

```
$Version 
lis = Riffle[RandomReal[100, 10^6], -1];
First @ AbsoluteTiming @ HistogramList[lis, {0, 6, 0.02}]
```

> "10.4.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (February 26, 2016)"
>
> 0.12289

Comment: That's great!  I've been complaining a lot to WRI about how badly Histogram performs and it seems they listened :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, the bug introduced in 10.2 where it cannot handle outliers remains in v 10.4. Calculating the HistogramList of CountryData's ExchangeRate will consume all available memory ... so be prepared to kill the kernel while watching the memory consumption if you try to execute this at home ... 

HistogramList@
 DeleteCases[
  QuantityMagnitude@CountryData[#, "ExchangeRate"] & /@ 
   CountryData[], _QuantityMagnitude]

Comment: @MarkKotanchek We are aware of that unfortunate issue. Regretfully, we do not yet have a fix, but are working on it.